# How can I get the values of a model class by Id and together, the values of another internal class?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have the class `Digit` and it has a many-to-many relationship with the `User` class.

How can I search for users related to a search by the digit ID?

```java
 @Entity
 public class Digit implements Serializable {

     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     private Integer id;

     // ...

     @JsonIgnore
     @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rDigit")
     private Set <User> user = new HashSet<>();

     // getters and setters
 }
```

My service:

```java
public Digit findDigitById(Integer id) {
    Optional<Digit> obj = digitRepository.findById(id); // This search does not bring the user
    if (obj.get() == null) {
        throw new ObjetoNaoEncontradoException("Some error: " + id);
    }

    return obj.get();
}
```

User class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

.....
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "USER_DIGIT", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "digit_id"))
    private Set<DigitoUnico> rDigit = new HashSet<>();

... getters and setters...
}
```

Comment: You also need to provide the code of the User class. We need to check that the mapping of the User to the Digits is correctly configured. Is there a @ManyToMany annotation on the Set<Digit> digits attribute in the User class, that refers to the Digit.user field?

Comment: i'll edit. But yes, I have the annotation in the user class.

Comment: Ok. I suppose that DigitoUnico = Digit, then the config looks OK. What's your error? ManyToMany relationships are lazy loaded.  So the request to retrieve the users will be triggered when accessing to them. You can enable the query logs to find what's wrong if it doesn't work as expected.